# I can not mapped Model and DTO could not execute statement; SQL [n/a] constraint [null]

Tags: java, spring-boot

This is base person entity it extends baseEntity which has only Id Auto creament

```
@Setter
@Getter
@Entity
public class Person extends BaseEntity {
    private String username;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "location_id")
    private Location location;
}
```

This is location Entity which also extends base entity

```
@Setter
@Getter
@Entity
public class Location extends BaseEntity {

    private double lat;
    private double lng;
    private String place;
    private String description;
}
```

Now I want to save peron entity which includes location table id also

```
@Data
public class PersonDTO {
    private String username;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Long location;
}
```

My PostMan Request is below

```
{
    
    "username":"bulbul",
    "firstName":"Bulbul",
    "lastName":"Ahmed",
    "location":1
}
```

My Service class is below

````
 public Person create(PersonDTO personDTO) {
        return this.personRepository.save(convertToPerson2(personDTO));
    }
 private Person convertToPerson2(PersonDTO personDTO) {
        modelMapper.getConfiguration().setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.LOOSE);
        Person person = modelMapper.map(personDTO, Person.class);
        return person;
    }
```
Now I faced a error :: Column 'location_id' cannot be null
 "could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement"

But I have also location table data in database which id is 1. Here Location Id can not map from personDTO
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the correct way to do this. You are mapping your `PersonDTO` to the `Person` class. But their `location` variable has completely different types. One is a `Location` and the other a `long`.

The correct way to do this would be to change the `PersonDTO` class like this:

```java
public class PersonDTO {
    private String username;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Location location; // Change this to the same type as in the Person class
}
```

And then, make a postman request this way:

```
{
    "username":"bulbul",
    "firstName":"Bulbul",
    "lastName":"Ahmed",
    "location":{
          "id": 1 // This part is important, you have an object which has an ID attribute..
     }
}
```

Make sure that the names and variable types are the same...

Good luck!